# Is it possible to create a generic CRUD in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a situation where i have to create CRUD for more than five entities. So, i was thinking if it is possible to create a generic CRUD so that i can have less code instead of creating individual CRUD for each entity.
I want to create a generic CRUDUtility which i can call from each entities controller methods, and from that utility i want to call generic Service class and generic Repository interface.

Here is what i want.

Utility which i can call from each entity controller:

```
@Component
public class CRUDUtility<T> {

    @Autowired
    private CRUDService<T> crudService;

}
```

Service class to call from CRUDUtility class.

```
@Service
public class CRUDService<T> {
    @Autowired
    private CRUDRepository<T> crudRepository;

    public T createEntity(T entityTypeParam) {

        return crudRepository.save(entityTypeParam);
    }

}
```

Repository to call from CRUDService:

```
@Repository
public interface CRUDRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Number> {


}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Consider using JPA, it has the methods you need, you just have to map your entities to the database tables.

Comment: Use JPARepository Interface instead CrudRepository

Comment: I have done that already, but i want a generic classes for service and repository

Comment: simply you can create one generic class that holds the type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create a generic CRUD

Since Spring 4 you can do autowiring by generic type.

```
public interface CRUDService<T> {
    List<T> listAll();

    T getById(Long id);

    T saveOrUpdate(T domainObject);

    void delete(Long id);
}

@Service
public FirstService implements CRUDService<First>{
.........................
}

@Service
public SecondService implements CRUDService<Second>{
.........................
}

@RestController
public MyController {
    @Autowired
    private CRUDService<First> firstService;

    @Autowired
    private CRUDService<Second> secondService;

}
```